# Can the Epson V700 be used with an Airport

Tags: snow-leopard, airport, scanning

I have a MacBook Pro, Snow Leopard, and an Epson V700 Scanner.

I'm thinking of buying an Airport Extreme or even better, an Airport Express (cos it's cheap).

Can I use the Epson V700 via the Airport as if it was connected locally via USB?

Apple talks about printers but not dedicated scanner, any ideas...?

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *cannot* scan over the network using the USB port of the airport express. It is only for printing.

Apple does not explicitly say that *scanners are not supported*, but it is not one of the [official uses of the USB hub](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2421). I have not heard anyone being successful in this, and AFAIK there are no hacks/third party s/w to do this (like [AirFoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) for streaming audio).

I personally have tried, in vain. I have a HP all in one, but the Snow Leopard does not recognize the scanner functions. I have to physically connect the scanner for this to work.